# Substring and setInterval to "read" through words

Tags: javascript, substring, setinterval

I´m just wondering how I can get the `substring(1,10)` to increase with 1 (using `setInterval`).
like (2,11)...(3,12)...(4,13) and so on, to the end of the paragraph.

I have done this:

```
function click(){
    var string = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML; 
    var sub = string.substring(1,10);

    if(sub == 0){   // wrong ?
        var interval = setInterval("increase()", 400)
    }
    function increase(){
        sub++;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sub;
```

Comment: P.S. It is considered better practice to write `setInterval(increase, 400)` as opposed to `setInterval("increase()", 400)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dpuy12qz/)?

```
var string = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML;
var offset = 0;

function increase() {
    var s = string.substring(0 + offset, 10 + offset);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = s;
    offset++;
}

var interval = setInterval(increase, 400)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks!
It was something like that I was looking for. But if I want to have a button that will start the setInterval, where do I place the setInterval? =)

<input type="button" value="read" id="increase()"/>

Comment: @BeautyFuzz you can add an EventListener for the event `click` and start the interval inside the function. Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dpuy12qz/1/